# Getting 409 The requested identifier already exists. when event does not exist

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

My code was running fine, but now I am getting 409 errors.

I am updating a Google calendar from my php system.

I am using a unique system key and my domain name to create a unique CalUID.

I then check these UID's against the existing entries by using

```
$service->events->listEvents()
```

For anything found in the returned list of events I use

```
$service->events->update().
```

For anything that is not returned, I add using `$service->events->insert()`, having set the CalUID using `$event->setICalUID()`

As I say, this has been running for years without any issues and the code at my end has not been changed.  Recently users said that their calendars were not being updated and on investigation I found that the `$service->events->insert()` call was throwing a 409 `"The requested identifier already exists."` exception.  Even though I know that the CalUID does not already exist, as it is not returned from the listEvents() call.

Has something changed?

Is it the CalUID that the 409 is referring to (I am not setting the event id, as the documentation seems to say that its either/or between CalUID and ID, not both)?

The $service object is created using:

```
$client = getGoogleAPIClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]  I need to see the code you are authorizing with as well as the calls that you are making and the Full error message

Comment: Are you 100% certain the UID does not exist? It is not because the user cannot see the event with listEvents that the event does not exist.